# Docker public repository not found when searched in DockerHub

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub, docker-image

I have just started to enhance my practical skills in Docker. I have an account and I have just created a public repository. But this doesn't actually contain any application at the moment, i.e its just empty.

So from what I have understood from a online course that I'm following is that I should be able to head over to the search page in DockerHub, [hub.docker.com/search](https://hub.docker.com/search) and search for my repository and then get the result back.

But for some reason DockerHub cant find it. I get the message " No results for **username/app**."

Have I missed to add something to the project which is causing this behaviour?

Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it takes some hours for the repository to be indexed so that it can be searched in DockerHub:

https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1342